# Grads error " not a variable or function name"

Tags: netcdf, era5, grads

when i was trying to plot climatology of peak wave period datavusing Grads ( era5 reanalysis product) The error shows 'pp1d not a variable or function name'. But the variable in the data is termed as pp1d itself. What could be the issue

when i was trying to plot climatology of peak wave period datavusing Grads ( era5 reanalysis product) The error shows 'pp1d not a variable or function name'. But the variable in the data is termed as pp1d itself.